# Bootstrap align navbar items to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-5

How do I align a navbar item to right?

I want to have the login and register to the right.
But everything I try does not seem to work.

[image: Picture of Navbar]

### This is what I have tried so far:

- `<div>` around the `<ul>` with the atribute: `style="float: right"`
- `<div>` around the `<ul>` with the atribute: `style="text-align: right"`
- tried those two things on the `<li>` tags
- tried all those things again with `!important` added to the end
- changed `nav-item` to `nav-right` in the `<li>`
- added a `pull-sm-right` class to the `<li>`
- added a `align-content-end` class to the `<li>`

### This is my code:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricingg</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav " >
      <li  class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li  class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  @yield('content')
</div>
```

Comment: Navbars are built with flexbox from alpha 6 version.

Comment: Yes, so what do I have to do to get it to align to the right.
I've already tried a couple flexbox things without any luck. :/

Answer (score 794, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5** (update 2021)

In Bootstrap 5 ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253543/align-nav-items-to-right-in-bootstrap-5/65254055#65254055)), `ml-auto` has been replaced with `ms-auto` to represent `start` instead of `left`. Since the Navbar is still based on *flexbox*, [auto **margins** OR **flexbox** utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#how-it-works) are still used to align Navbar content.

For example, use `me-auto`...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Menu </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Bootstrap 5 right align Navbar content](https://www.codeply.com/p/LJy7ooFrBP)

---

**Bootstrap 4** (original answer)

Bootstrap has [*many* different ways to align navbar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items). `float-right` won't work because the navbar is now `flexbox`.

You can use `mr-auto` for auto right margin on the **1st** (left) `navbar-nav`.
**Alternatively**, `ml-auto` could be used on the **2nd** (right) `navbar-nav` , or if you just have a single `navbar-nav`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/go/P0G393rzfm

There are also flexbox utils. For example use `justify-content-end` on the collapse menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Or when you have 2 `navbar-nav`s, use `justify-content-between` in `navbar-collapse` would work to even the space between the navbar-navs:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
               ..
     </ul>
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
           ..
     </ul>
 </div>
```

---

**Update for Bootstrap 4.0 and newer**

As of Bootstrap 4 beta, `ml-auto` will still work to push items to the right. Just be aware the the `navbar-toggleable-` classes have changed to `navbar-expand-*`

Updated [navbar right for Bootstrap 4](http://www.codeply.com/go/P0G393rzfm)

---

Another frequent Bootstrap 4 Navbar right alignment scenario includes a button on the right that *remains outside the mobile collapse* nav so that it is always shown at all widths.

[Right align button that is always visible](https://www.codeply.com/go/ljI9F6aRLk)

[image]

[image]

Related: [Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items/20362024#20362024)

Comment: `mr-auto` doesn't work if the right-most item is a `dropdown`. The dropdown items spill over the right edge of the page.

Comment: It works: https://www.codeply.com/go/P0G393rzfm - the issue is not `mr-auto` as the question is about aligning right which works. Post a new question if you have concerns with the dropdown, but you're most likely referring to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867258/relocating-bootstrap-4-navigation-dropdown-menu/43868074#43868074

Comment: You can also add `.dropdown-menu-right` to right-aligned dropdowns in the navbar. Not doing so can cut off the dropdown at certain widths.

Comment: @ZimSystem thank you for your answers. I have been following your answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items . I have a question how can I achieve one item to be on the left side and one item on the right side ?

Comment: In http://www.codeply.com/go/P0G393rzfm, you've shown one ul on the left and one ul on the right. That was achieved by adding _mr-auto_ to the first one. But what if I have only one ul? I don't want to create an empty ul just for aligning another one to the right.

Comment: .justify-content-between worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I was needing to pull only one item inside a "nav" element to the right, so adds "ml-auto" to this child item solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: If you want two Navs, with them pushed left and right, justify-content-between worked well for me.

Comment: Nice! Just add "ml-auto" on your first ul @SantoshKumar

Answer (score 176):

In my case, I wanted just one set of navigation buttons / options and found that this will work:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarCollapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, you will add `justify-content-end` to the div and omit `mr-auto` on the list.

Here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/craigvantonder/pen/MJwLWb).

Comment: @numediaweb In the OPs example, he uses two elements within the nav, aligning one left and one right; where I used only one and aligned it to the right. It's not the right answer but it's helpful as an answer to a slight variation of the question ;)

Comment: This works for a single navbar-nav, but the [`mr-auto` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41513784/171456) is used in the [Bootstrap docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/).

Comment: `mr-auto` is used in docs, but not to align items to the left. This answer is semantically correct as mentioned in this article: http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/01/06/bootstrap-4-alpha-6/

Comment: The question is are you trying to align 2 list of links or 1. If just 1, your answer works and was very helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me, but I don't know why the one above this answer doesn't work.

Comment: `float-right` works the same way as `justify-content-end` , as long as `mr-auto` is removed.

Answer (score 78):

For those who is still struggling with this issue in BS4 simply try below code -

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Comment: No - that aligns everything to the right. The question says he only wants to align a single item to the right.

Comment: Check the official doc about [`m*-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) it pushes content to the left or right depending on where you put the class

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY, yes `ml-auto` does push content to the rightmost position, but I just wondered why `mr-0` cannot do the job?

Comment: @NickG if you want some items aligned left and others right, you can just have multiple `<ul>` elements, each with the appropriate `m*-auto`

Answer (score 52):

**On Bootstrap 4**

If you want to align brand to your left and all the navbar-items to right, change the default `mr-auto` to `ml-auto`

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Comment: Any example for this?

Answer (score 36):

On `Bootsrap 4.0.0-beta.2`, none of the answers listed here worked for me. Finally, the Bootstrap site gave me the solution, not via its doc but via its page source code...

Getbootstrap.com align their right `navbar-nav` to the right with the help of the following class: `ml-md-auto`.

Comment: Worked beautifully for me. Nothing else did.

Comment: Tried your suggestion of looking up the Bootstrap webpage source itself and, as of this writing (16th Jan, 2021), it's `ms-md-auto`. At least that worked in my case.

Answer (score 18):

Use this code to move items to the right.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
```

Comment: that will not work when you have a collapsed Menu, however, with the ml-auto it will still work because when the menu is collapsed, the <li> items still take 100% of the width so no margin will be applied.

Comment: For me only this solution worked i am using bootstrap version 4

Answer (score 14):

Use `ml-auto` instead of `mr-auto` after applying `nav` justify-content-end to the `ul`

Answer (score 12):

Just add `mr-auto` class at `ul`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
```

If you have menu list in both side you can do something like this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">left 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">left 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">left disable</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want Home, Features and Pricing on left immediately after your `nav-brand`, and then login and register on right then wrap the two lists in `<div>` and use `.justify-content-between`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between">
<ul>....</ul>
<ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

In bootstrap v4.3 just add `ml-auto` in `<ul class="navbar-nav">`
Ex:`<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">`

Answer (score 5):

use the flex-row-reverse class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-hospital-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-row-reverse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#" style="background-color:#666">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a</li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Doctors</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Specialists</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's little change in boostrap 4.
To align navbar to right side, you've to make only two changes.
they are:

1. in `navbar-nav` class add `w-100` as `navbar-nav w-100` to make width as 100
2. in `nav-item dropdown` class add `ml-auto` as `nav-item dropdown ml-auto` to make margin left as auto.

If you didn't understand, please refer the image that i've attached to this.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/actionanand/pen/wvvoxMj)

[image]

**Full source code**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

For bootstrap 4.3.1, I was using nav-pills and nothing worked for me except this:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end ml-auto">
    <li ....</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case Bootstrap v5, I wanted just one set of navigation  options to the right side:

> just add "ms-auto" in ul.

And it helped me.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="services.php" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answers surprisingly didn't work for me so here is my approach. To align the **login** and **register** navigation bar items to the right you can make use of either of these two ways:

1. **pull-right**:
   Modify the unordered list tag for login and register as

   `<ul class="navbar-nav pull-right">`
2. **navbar-right**:
   Modify the unordered list tag for login and register as

   `<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">`

Answer (score 1):

- but the nav item you want to align to right in  alone
- put it outside the  of main nav but in the same , like that:

  ```
  <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end ms-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#" aria-expanded="false">Contact support</a>
     </li>

     <li class="nav-item ">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#" aria-expanded="false">Log in</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
  ```

use  `justify-content-end ms-auto`

Answer (score 0):

I am running Angular 4 (v.4.0.0) and ng-bootstrap (Bootstrap 4). This code won't all be relevant but hoping people can pick and choose what works. It took me sometime to find a solution to get my items to justify right, collapse properly and to implement a dropdown off my google (using OAuth) profile picture.

```
<div id="header" class="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-faded fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img alt='Brand' src='../assets/images/logo-white.png' class='navbar-logo-img d-inline-block align-top '>
          <span class="navbar-logo-text">Oncoscape</span>
        </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav float-left">
        <a class="navbar-items nav-item nav-link active " *ngIf='authenticated' (click)='goDashboard()'>
          <span class="fa fa-dashboard"></span>Dashboard
        </a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link navbar-items active" href="http://resources.sttrcancer.org/oncoscape-contact">
          <span class="fa fa-comments"></span>Feedback
        </a>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <img *ngIf='user && authenticated'  class="navbar-pic" src={{user.thumbnail}} alt="Smiley face">
          </a>
          <div *ngIf='user && authenticated' class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="toProfile()">Account</a>
            <div class="dropdown-item">
              <app-login></app-login>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4 beta, sample navbar with elements aligned to the right side is:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricingg</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the bootstrap flex box helps 
us to control the placement and alignment of your navigation element.
for the problem above adding mr-auto is a better solution to it .

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricingg</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav  " >
      <li  class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li  class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  @yield('content')
</div>
```

other placement may include

```
fixed- top
    fixed bottom
    sticky-top
```

Answer (score 0):

The working example for BS `v4.0.0-beta.2`:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricingg</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container-fluid">
      container content
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all above fails, I added 100% width to the navbar class in CSS.  Until then mr auto wasn't working for me on this project using 4.1.

Answer (score -1):

Find the 69 line in the verndor-prefixes.less and write it following:

```css
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just copied this from one of the getbootstrap pages for the released version 4 which worked much better than the above

```
<div class="d-none d-xl-block col-xl-2 bd-toc float-md-right">
    <ul class="section-nav">
         <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
         <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#classes">Classes</a></li>
         <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#mixins">Mixins</a></li>
         <li class="toc-entry toc-h2"><a href="#responsive">Responsive</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm new to stack overflow and new to front end development. This is what worked for me. So I did not want list items to be displayed.

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
  } 
  
 #loginButton{
 
 margin-right:2px;
 
 }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active hidden">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item hidden">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item hidden">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="loginButton"><a href="#">Log In</a></button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><a href="#">Register</a></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```