# In Bootstrap v4, what has replaced "navbar-right"?

Tags: navbar, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using navbar whitout lists. How do you make navbar brand stay left, and the links go right? Before it was just "navbar-right", what about now?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align navbar item to the right in bootstrap 4 alpha 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/align-navbar-item-to-the-right-in-bootstrap-4-alpha-6)

Comment: It has been replaced by `ml-auto`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer now.

You have to add "ml-auto".

```
<div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Answer (score 1):

A more complete working example for bootstrap4 alpha 6 here. http://www.codeply.com/go/P0G393rzfm This new behavior occurred in alpha 6 release of bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it as a replacement but here is the class you could use to make the menu left-aligned.

```
<div class = "navbar-nav ms-lg-suto> 
.......
.......
.......
</div>
```