# Align navbar bootstrap 4 to the right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the new version of Bootstrap for a personnal project. I tried to make a navbar, and I want the links to be aligned to the right, and I looked for a solution but I couldn't find how to do it.
Here's my code

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">taïho sushi</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Présentation</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align navbar item to the right in bootstrap 4 alpha 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/align-navbar-item-to-the-right-in-bootstrap-4-alpha-6)

Answer (score 3):

Use the new `ml-auto` class which sets `margin-left:auto` and pushes the content to the right.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">taïho sushi</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Présentation</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/LOijH7cTrt)

Answer (score 0):

use `navbar-right` class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">taïho sushi</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Présentation</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it seems that the problem should be another, because its working here.

Comment: navbar-right is deprecated in VS 4 alpha 6. [Now ml-auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/align-navbar-item-to-the-right-in-bootstrap-4-alpha-6) is used.