# Bootstrap - how to align input to right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I copied navbar from this example:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Nawigacja zamknieta w kontenerze</h3>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

but my search button isn't right aligned?
What's going on?
How can I change it?

[image]

Comment: it's right aligned. Make sure you're using the bootstrap 4 CSS, not 3. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpXVeG

Comment: Are you using the v4-alpha css?

Comment: Thanks. It was a problem

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/align-navbar-item-to-the-right-in-bootstrap-4-alpha-6

Answer (score -1):

You can use pull-right properties into your button.