# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Menu Items Right

Tags: bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

As you see in the picture below, when I click on the bell icon, a dropdown menu appears at the bottom-right of the icon. I want this dropdown menu to appear at bottom-left instead of bottom-right. What should I do?

[image]

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Use the `dropdown-menu-end` class on the `dropdown-menu` to align the items inside the menu right..

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/kWLLKdjdpC

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

Use the `dropdown-menu-right` class to align the items inside the menu right..

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-right">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/6Mf9aK0P8G

Comment: Works to both position menu within viewport when off-screen and align `text-right`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Renaming classes in this way is not cool!

Answer (score 19):

**Update for Bootstrap4-Beta**:

Because there is a [bug in bootstrap4 beta](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23308) i had to add

```
.dropdown-menu-right { 
    right: 0; 
    left: auto; 
}
```

to make it work.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping to avoid adding CSS, but this did the trick.

Comment: This was the ONLY thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

`.dropdown-menu-right` class has a different behaviour if it's inside a `.navbar`. You can read the "Heads up" in the docs here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

Actually to solve I use this class:

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu-right { 
    right: 0; 
    left: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Bootstrap 5

@Zim 's answer is likely the most correct [as suggested in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment).

Despite that, the only way I managed to make it work was using the `end-0` class instead.

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu end-0">
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, I was getting mad already. THIS and ONLY THIS helped me! I'm using BS 5.1, which comes with the current asp.net core 6 template version for blazor (not that it matters) I read the official BS docu and many forums. The consensus is for BS 5 we should use  `dropdown-menu-end` and for older verisons (BS 4) `dropdown-menu-right` - but BOTH did NOT WORK AT ALL for me. `end-0` however does. WHY IS THAT? WHY does official docu lie !!!

Answer (score 1):

It's little change in boostrap 4.
To align navbar to right side, you've to make only two changes.
they are:

1. in `navbar-nav` class add `w-100` as `navbar-nav w-100` to make width as 100
2. in `nav-item dropdown` class add `ml-auto` as `nav-item dropdown ml-auto` to make margin left as auto.

If you didn't understand, please refer this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474527/10907720

Answer (score 1):

I Chaned it by add *dir="rtl"*

```
<div class="dropdown-menu " dir="rtl" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with an additional difficulty because my menu is created in PHP - the number of elements and dropdown content is not fixed.

Here is a solution that **centers dropdowns when possible**, otherwise **align them on the left or right** to **prevent them from exceeding the viewport**:

```
var $maxWidthElement = $('.navbar'),
    maxWidth = $maxWidthElement.width();

var positionDropdowns = function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').each(function() {
        var $navItem = $(this).closest('.dropdown'),
            dropdownWidth = $(this).outerWidth(),
            dropdownOffsetLeft = $navItem.offset().left,
            dropdownOffsetRight = maxWidth - (dropdownOffsetLeft + dropdownWidth),
            linkCenterOffsetLeft = dropdownOffsetLeft + $navItem.outerWidth() / 2;

        if ((linkCenterOffsetLeft - dropdownWidth / 2 > 0) & (linkCenterOffsetLeft + dropdownWidth / 2 < maxWidth)) {
            // center the dropdown menu if possible
            $(this).css('left', -(dropdownWidth / 2 - $navItem.outerWidth() / 2));
        } else if ((dropdownOffsetRight < 0) & (dropdownWidth < dropdownOffsetLeft + $navItem.outerWidth())) {
            // set the dropdown menu to left if it exceeds the viewport on the right
            $(this).addClass('dropdown-menu-right');
        } else if (dropdownOffsetLeft + dropdownWidth > maxWidth) {
            // full width if the dropdown is too large to fit on the right
            $(this).css({
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                width:
                    $(this)
                        .closest('.container')
                        .width() + 'px'
            });
        }
    });
};

var resizeTimer;

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        maxWidth = $maxWidthElement.width();
        positionDropdowns();
    }, 250);
});

positionDropdowns();
window.onresize = positionDropdowns;
```

https://codepen.io/migli/pen/RELPPj