# Bootstrap 5 navbar dropdown-menu leaves screen

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a menu that is aligned to the right. The last menu is a dropdown menu. But the dropdown menu items doesn't stay on the screen. Half of it leaves the screen. I have been googling but I can't find the class that kepps it on screen.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="ms-auto order-0">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><img src="./img/BMB-logo.svg" width="75" height="75"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you add the Bootstrap class `dropdown-menu-end` to the `ul,` the dropdown will align with the right side of the dropdown button. The info's on the Bootstrap 5 [dropdown page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#alignment-options).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867258/bootstrap-4-navbar-dropdown-menu-items-right/43868074#43868074), the `dropdown-menu` needs to be right aligned. In Bootstrap 5, `dropdown-menu-right` has changed to `dropdown-menu-end`...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="ms-auto order-0">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/75" width="75" height="75"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/kWLLKdjdpC)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me due to the following CSS style:

```
.dropdown-menu[style] {
    right: auto !important;
}
```

which overrides the `right:0;` property of `.dropdown-menu-end`. Removing the `!important` or adding it to the `.dropdown-menu-end` forces the dropdown to align right as intended.