# Simple bootstrap Navbar that doesn't collapse and has button to right

Tags: html, css, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-4

New to bootstrap, I'm using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 and I'm struggling to set up a simple navbar. I want the brad on the left and a simple button on the right. I've looked at the documentation and can't seem to solve my issue. I know it has something to do with mr-auto or something similar. I've tried float-right, but that doesn't work. My button just sits below the brand on the left. here's my code....

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Brand</a>

    <div class="mr-auto">
      <a href=""><button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button></a>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't put a <button> in an <a>. It isn't semantic or syntactic, it won't work as designed and it will confuse future maintainers of your code.

Comment: If you are new to Bootstrap then I would suggest focusing on 3.3.x. There are way more examples and help that will get you up to speed then you can focus on migration to 4 closer to release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using helper classes from bootstrap. 
Documentation: [Bootstrap Responsive floats](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/responsive-helpers/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="float-left">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Brand</a>
      </div>       
      <div class="float-right">
         <div class="mr-auto">
         <a href=""><button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 float-right" type="submit">Search</button></a>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div> 
</nav>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="float-left">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Brand</a>
      </div>       
      <div class="float-right">
         <div class="mr-auto">
         <a href=""><button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 float-right" type="submit">Search</button></a>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div> 
</nav>
```

Comment: That's great, exactly what I did. One slight issue was the navbar seemed to fill the whole page. Solved this by wrapping everything in a div with a class of row.

Answer (score 0):

If you had shared the css along with html it would have been helpful. "navbar-right" class will float the element only above 768px width. If you want it to float right for all the screen sizes then use styling of float:right.

`.mr-auto{
  float:right;
}`

I have attached the working example of it http://jsfiddle.net/b1xpte8q/

Comment: Just using the linked bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically a dup of: [Bootstrap 4 align navbar item to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-item-to-the-right/41513784#41513784)

The separate issue of making it not collapse, is a matter of using `navbar-toggle-xl` which prevents the mobile collapsed navbar...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xl navbar-light bg-faded">
   <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">My Brand</a>
   <a href=""><button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button></a>
</nav>
```

https://www.bootply.com/CTXFJPFIK4