# CSS float-right not working in Bootstrap 4 Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to get my nav links to float to the right of my navbar, but I can't get it to work. I've tried using the ".float-right", "float-xs-right", and "justify-content-end" bootstrap 4 class, along with using "float: right !important;" in my CSS file, and it still won't work.

Here is the HTML for the navbar of my website:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="88px">
                Scervino Lawn Service
            </div>
            <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#navbar {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #9CCC58;
}
```

I'm relatively new to the Bootstrap 4 framework, so it's possible that I might just be making a dumb mistake, but hopefully someone can help me. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `.justify-content-between` on the parent `.row` to move the flex children to the far edges of the row.

```css
#navbar {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #9CCC58;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="88px">
                Scervino Lawn Service
            </div>
            <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 49):

**Bootstrap 5** (update 2021)

The Bootstrap 5 Navbar still uses flexbox, but the concept of **right** and **left**, have *changed* to **start** and **end** for new [RTL support](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/#approach). Therefore, the class names have changed...

- `float-right` --> `float-end`
- `float-left` --> `float-start`
- `ml-*` --> `ms-*`
- `pl-*` --> `ps-*`
- `mr-*` --> `me-*`
- `pr-*` --> `pe-*`

BUT, remember **floats don't work with flexbox**. The best approach for right alignment in the Navbar is to use `ms-auto` (margin-left: auto) or `justify-content-end`.

[See this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-items-to-the-right)

---

**Bootstrap 4**

The original answer no longer works in Bootstrap 4, and it's not good practice to use Bootstrap's `.row` in the navbar component. The `.row` should only be used for grid columns.

Now that Bootstrap 4 is **flexbox**, one way to align navbar components is using the [auto-margin utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins), such as `ml-auto` which is a shortcut for CSS `margin-left:auto`. This can be used to push the `nav` to the right...

https://www.codeply.com/go/ZAGhCX5lpq

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img src=".." width="88px">
             Scervino Lawn Service
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or the [flexbox utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) like `justify-content-between` can be used on the `container` inside the navbar...

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container justify-content-between">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img src=".." width="88px">
             Scervino Lawn Service
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just notice that in this case `justify-content-between` works because there are only 2 navbar components (navbar-brand and nav).

Comment: This solved my issue with the tip `right => start` and `left => end` using bootstrap 5

Comment: @Zim Thanks for keeping the answer updated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Bootstrap 4.0.0 Alpha 6 and it works, here's the example: https://repl.it/JwMq/0

I just added this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

And a extra `</div>`

Comment: I have that code and it still doesn't work. And oops sorry I forgot to add that div when I was pasting my code in my question but the extra div is there in my original code