# Bootstrap make an element at the end of the row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap framework and need to make an element at the end of the row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div end</div>
</div>
```

These divs are in a row -it is desired. But I need the "end div" element to pull to the right corner of the row. I tried many Bootstrap classes. but somewhat they stay adjacent.

Comment: did u tried pull-left on div 1 ?

Comment: from the doc `In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.`

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494882/css-float-right-not-working-in-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox or `display: flex` on `row` class you can just use [`ml-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) on second div which will add `margin-left` auto and push that div to the right side.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div class="ml-auto">div end</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is from the Bootstrap docs. By default each column is `aligned`/`floated` left, but with this the space in between the columns is equally distributed:

```
<div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div> Div 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div> Div End </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It makes use of `flexbox` and there are several more options available to align your columns inside a row, or even `wrap` and `nest` them.

Read about it with this link: [Bootstrap docs - Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

With Bootstrap 4 there is another option for this. Because it makes use of `flexbox` you can add the `.ml-auto` to the last `div` in a `row`, but you should be wary of the overall `row` `width` (It should not exceed 12/12 columns widths). You can read anything about it in the Bootstrap 4 docs in the Layout/Grid section.

Comment: the only good answer that respect the Boostrap rules ! add the container and it will be perfect ;)

Comment: Ah, well ... I should by more wary of the code that is provided ... I do have the habit of rewriting it like I would write it in the first place! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="">
    <div class="float-left">div 1</div>
    <div class="float-right">div end</div>
</div>
</div>
```