# Bootstrap 4 - Horizontally Align Inline Lists

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm migrating a website from Bootstrap 3.7 to Bootstrap 4. In my site, I have a banner across the top that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Item 1   Item 2                      Item A Item B [note] |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The items in the left are dynamic. The items on the right are dynamic. The [note] piece shows occasionally. I had this working correctly with Bootstrap 3.7. However, when migrating to Bootstrap 4, the content is all left aligned. You can see the result in this [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/hj3ojssERR). The code looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="d-inline-flex" style="width:100%;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-inline-flex">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <ul class="list-inline-mb-0">
          <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>          
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav list-inline justify-content-end">
      <li class="list-inline-item pt-0 pr-1 pb-0 pl-0">Aug.</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">29th</li>                
    </ul>

    <div class="nav-item sub-nav-title float-md-right pr-0">[note]</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I don't understand why the items are all left-aligned instead of filling the width of the page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-item-to-the-right/41513784#41513784) float won't work in the navbar since it's now flexbox. Use `ml-auto` to push the items to the right.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="d-inline-flex" style="width:100%;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-inline-flex">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <ul class="list-inline-mb-0">
          <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>          
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav list-inline ml-auto">
      <li class="list-inline-item pt-0 pr-1 pb-0 pl-0">Aug.</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">29th</li>                
    </ul>
    <div class="nav-item sub-nav-title float-md-right pr-0">[note]</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/CGBAvf8r1q

Or, you can use `mr-auto` on the first nav.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put your `[note]` item in with your second unordered list and and use `justify-content-between` in your wrapping `div` element? It would look something like this...

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="d-inline-flex justify-content-between" style="width:100%;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-inline-flex">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <ul class="list-inline-mb-0">
          <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>          
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item pt-0 pr-1 pb-0 pl-0">Aug.</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">29th</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">[note]</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```