# Navbar li elements not floating to right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need a help to make my li elements float to the right of navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank" id="heading">Samrat Luitel</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are your li elements the same width as the ul parent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [Grids](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) in this scenario

You give grid of `col-4` to you List Item and Grid `col-8` to your Brand Name.

In that way you will be able to achieve what you are looking for.

And a little bit of CSS styling will make it better.

---

```css
.navbar-right{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-fixed-top topnav col-12" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header col-8">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank" id="heading">Samrat Luitel</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: isn't it on the right side of navbar? If it's not what you are expecting, please show us a picture of what you are looking for.

Comment: they are on left with the navbar-brand

Comment: @SamratLuitel, please check the edit. This will work.

Comment: It is working much better but not sticking to corner

Comment: Well, now it is. Please check.

Comment: Thanks but why earlier just putting the class navbar-right it was not working

Comment: It's because, in `Bootstrap 4` `nav` is using Flexbox. Better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-item-to-the-right)

Answer (score -1):

Where are your classes coming from? Easiest way to force them to float right would be to define it in an external style sheet or in the HTML document. To do it in HTML all you need to do is:

```
    <style>
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: right;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: I'll have a look, if you use inspect element and select the `li`'s then look on the right (on chrome) you can see where the styles are coming from. To test it on different areas at the top of the style column type `float: right` and see if it changes anything

Comment: does tether absent causes error. I found that on console