# ul won't float right in navbar bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: css-float, html-lists, bootstrap-4

I see other people have asked this question but I don't see any correct answers.  I have tried float-right and float-xs-right.  Here is the full code on the entire page per request.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap v4 alpha or v4 beta? The code required depends on which version of the framework you are using since it was changed in the beta.

Comment: I am in beta.  The only thing I saw in the documentation is the got rid of pull-right

Answer (score 1):

> using 4.0.0-beta.2  -

```
 <ul class='navbar-nav mr-auto'> 
 //sets margin-right: auto !important 
 // adds space to the right - moving div content left 
 </ul>

 <ul class='navbar-nav ml-auto'>
 //sets margin-left: auto !important
 // adds space to the left - moving div content right 
</ul>

<ul class='navbar-nav mx-auto'>
 //sets margin-left: auto !important
 //sets margin-right: auto !important
 // centers content by evenly adding space either side
</ul>
```

Comment: can you show the full page code? most likely a preceding div class style affecting your nav layout flex.

Comment: I just tested it again in a completely clean document and it still doesn't pull-right.

Comment: I just updated the original post to show the full code for the entire page.

Comment: ahh - I see - not mr-auto, but ml-auto - problem solved.  Thanks!

Comment: cool do i get a correct tick? this may be a duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-item-to-the-right?rq=1

Comment: I tried.  Did it work?  It said those with less than 15 rep points don't count or something like that.