# Bootstrap 4 align two navbar menu buttons to right side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following layout with two different menus in the navbar, like this:

[image]

The navbar menu collapses into two different menu buttons, which is what I want. However I would like the buttons to align side by side to the right. I cant figure out how to get the button on the left to move to the right?

[image]

Code (using bootstrap 4 beta):

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand logo-font" href="#">
            Brand
        </a>
        <!-- links toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- account toggle --> 
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="links">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Other
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
                </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="account">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

[Link to codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/A9wDhZGw7f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's just one little class that you need to add to the first toggler and that is the `ml-auto` class.

That is short for "**margin-left auto**" which is a flexbox auto margin utility.

Here's the working code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand logo-font" href="#">
            Brand
        </a>

        <!-- links toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <!-- account toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="links">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Other
                        </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="account">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I thought I was likely missing something simple.

Comment: It would be great if they work as i would expect. Like, click on first, open submenu, click on second to close first and open second. Click on first again, close the second one and open first.

Comment: In bootstrap5 use `ms-auto` instead! See -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/41513784/11918697