# Bootstrap 4: Justify menu to right in navbar?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am working with the Bootstrap 4 default navbar and I just want to add a collapsing menu that is positioned on the right, not the left, when not collapsed.

I have tried adding `text-right` and `float-right`, but neither are actually moving the menu to the right.

[Here is a bootply](https://www.bootply.com/n2wzGQrP1k) showing the issue.

Here also is a snippet, since StackOverflow wants me to use one, though I don't think it'll be wide enough to show the non-collapsed menu:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">&#x2630;</button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ml-auto` class to `ul` tag containing menu

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <li class="active nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Homes</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element `.collapse.navbar-collapse` requires `.justify-content-end` class as it is positioned with flex (`display: flex`) and takes full remaining width of your navbar.

The other answers with `.ml-auto` are perfectly valid. The difference between these two is that `.justify-content-end` will make all elements inside navbar-collapse [stick to the right](https://www.bootply.com/7o22h42ULY), whereas `.ml-auto` will only do the same for the ones inserted after your `ul.nav.nav-bar`, so the ones on the left [can still stick to the left](https://www.bootply.com/wnAX31KSIZ). You can choose the one most appropriate to you, and feel free to combine these two for more sophisticated layouts.

Your updated Boolply can be found [**here**](https://www.bootply.com/SeByhHtdLt).

```
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">☰</button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add     `.navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse{
flex-direction: column-reverse;}` in your style sheet. thanks

```css
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse{
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">&#x2630;</button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav  ml-auto"> <!-- here -->
                <li class="active nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```