# Bootstrap 5 flex-grow-0 doesn't work like it is supposed to

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Here is my code snippet for my navbar.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-white">
  <div class="container my-2">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand text-dark fw-bold">
      Rakshit Deshmukh
    </a>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info ml-auto">Contact me</button>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#collapseNav"
    >
      <span class="fas fa-bars text-dark"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="collapseNav">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link text-dark h6 mx-3 my-auto">
          Blogs
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-W8fXfP3gkOKtndU4JGtKDvXbO53Wy8SZCQHczT5FMiiqmQfUpWbYdTil/SxwZgAN"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

Here is the output navbar which the current code produces:

[image: Output Navbar of the current code]

Here's what I want to produce as the navbar:

[image]

Is it the CDN's issue?

As it so happens, for this project, I migrated from the previous Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 and hence these issues are rising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't because `flex-grow-0` has changed. It's because `ml-auto` is now `ms-auto`...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-white">
    <div class="container my-2">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand text-dark fw-bold"> Rakshit Deshmukh </a>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info ms-auto">Contact me</button>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNav">
            <span class="fas fa-bars text-dark"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="collapseNav">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link text-dark h6 mx-3 my-auto"> Blogs </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/p/i9uVTwK3tf

Bootstrap 5 now has RTL support so right concepts of "**left**" and "**right**" have changed to "**start**" and "**end**". Therefore, m**l**-auto is now m**s**-auto.

Also see: [Bootstrap align navbar items to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-align-navbar-items-to-the-right/41513784#41513784)