# How to align navbar items right in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html

I know there are already a lot of questions asked about how to do this, but I am not understanding where exactly should I place the class in my code. I am using Bootstrap 5.1.3.
Also, could someone identify if I am doing/including any "extra stuff" that is redundant or I can remove.
My Code:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light fixed-top navbar-expand-md mr-auto">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    Shubham Salunke
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#home"> Home </a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#about"> About </a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#projects"> Works </a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#social"> Social Media </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: might be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-align-navbar-items-to-the-right

Comment: Okay, I managed to get that done, but according to the post you linked, I should have used me-auto for flexbox end, however, I think I the flex-direction as row-reverse, so I used ms-auto and it works just as expected, so thank you!